# is there any tool or IDE to debug R packages and run it step by step?

Tags: r

I am interested in some R packages, and want to understand how it works, is there any tool to run the method in package step by step and print the intermediate output?

Comment: do you mean 'debug()'???  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The two previous answers already told you what base R, and add-on packages can do.

As far as IDEs go, you have two choices:

1. The [StatET plugin for Eclipse](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) has some features for this (which I haven't used).
2. ESS for Emacs where the newest ESS releases have integrated `ess-tracebug` which does this too. Here is some [documentation from when ess-tracebug was still a third-party project](http://code.google.com/p/ess-tracebug/) and not part of [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org) proper.  While I am an ESS user, I haven't tried this either yet.

Here is the help for ess-tracebug to give a flavor of what it can do:

```
Documentation:

Default ess-tracebug key bindings:

* Breakpoints:

 b   . Set BP (repeat to cycle BP type) . `ess-bp-set'
 B   . Set conditional BP               . `ess-bp-set-conditional'
 k   . Kill BP                          . `ess-bp-kil'
 K   . Kill all BPs                     . `ess-bp-kill-all'
 t   . Toggle BP state                  . `ess-bp-toggle-state'
 l   . Set logger BP                    . `ess-bp-set-logger'
 C-n . Goto next BP                     . `ess-bp-next'
 C-p . Goto previous BP                 . `ess-bp-previous'

* General Debugging:

 `   . Show R Traceback                     . `ess-show-R-traceback'
 e   . Toggle error action (repeat to cycle). `ess-dbg-toggle-error-action'
 d   . Flag for debugging                   . `ess-dbg-flag-for-debugging'
 u   . Unflag for debugging                 . `ess-dbg-unflag-for-debugging'
 w   . Watch window                         . `ess-watch'

* Navigation to errors (emacs general functionality):

 C-x `, M-g n   . `next-error'
 M-g p          . `previous-error'

* Interactive Debugging:

 c   . Continue                  . `ess-dbg-command-c'
 n   . Next step                 . `ess-dbg-command-n'
 p   . Previous step             . `previous-error'
 q   . Quit debugging            . `ess-dbg-command-Q'
 1..9. Enter recover frame       . `ess-dbg-command-digit'
 0   . Exit recover (also q,n,c) . `ess-dbg-command-digit'

* Input Ring:

 i   . Goto input event marker forwards     . `ess-dbg-goto-input-event-marker'
 I   . Goto input event marker backwards    . `ess-dbg-goto-input-event-marker'

* Misc:
 s   . Source current file  . `ess-tracebug-source-current-file'
 ?   . Show this help       . `ess-tracebug-show-help'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the R instructions `debug` and `browser` will let you do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

There is the debug package, combined with the mtrace function.  There is also a new debug module for Eclipse (as Dirk mentions in his answer), and a similar capabilities might be added to Rstudio in the future.  Once these are in place, the question would be how to have them debug the relevant functions.  Which would basically mean getting the list of all the functions you are interested in and tracking them.

p.s: you might have a look at this - http://www.r-bloggers.com/what-does-this-package-look-like/

Answer (score 1):

The IDE in Revolution R includes convenient visual debugging features similar to those found in MS Visual Studio. Although the software is proprietary and requires paying for license, you could always download the free academic version.

http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/downloads/free-academic.php